# Оптимизация SQL в PostrgeSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Возможно нужно добавить какой-то еще индекс?

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (all_name) all_name
FROM os.global g
WHERE g.all_name like 'khust_%'
```

Index table:

```
CREATE INDEX g_idx_all_name
  ON os.global
  USING btree
  (all_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Comment: Больше одного индекса на таблицу в запросе оптимизатор не использует. так что оптимизировать нечего

Comment: Можно оптимизировать, записав запрос покороче `SELECT DISTINCT  all_name ...` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не смотря на то, что у меня был индекс, он не использовался.
Проверил это можно с помощью команды `EXPLAIN`. Должно быть что то вроде `Index Scan`, а не `Seq Scan`

Проблема была в `like 'khust_%'`.
Нужно расширить триграммный поиск:
`CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm`.
Мне пришлось еще создать новый индекс.

Полезные ссылки:

[Помогите составить индекс для запросов вида LIKE %text%](http://www.sql.ru/forum/1053727/pomogite-sostavit-indeks-dlya-zaprosov-vida-like-text);

[Оптимизация запросов. Основы EXPLAIN в PostgreSQL](https://habrahabr.ru/post/203320/);

[pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html);

[Using trigrams against typos](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/09/06-pg_trgm-suggestions.html);

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT all_name FROM os.global g WHERE g.all_name like 'khust% AND length(g.all_name) = 6'` индексируется старым образом? только сейчас сообразил, что подвох в `_`. Не припомню чтобы сам его применял.